# PyAutoGui the mouse wont move

Tags: python, subprocess, pyautogui

I have this code:

```
import pyautogui
import subprocess

# iniciate the program
subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\someprogram\someprogram.exe'])

# Abrir folder
pyautogui.moveTo(110, 54, duration=1)
pyautogui.click(clicks=1, interval=1, button='left')
```

but the mouse wont move it the program initiates from new, it only moves it the exec is already open, what could it be?

Comment: Replace subprocess.call with subprocess.Popen

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely a permission's issue. Have you tried running the program as an admin?